# Maximum Likelihood Estimator - Beta Distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, beta-distribution

I'm taking a Mathematical Statistics course and trying to work through a homework problem that reads:

Let Y1, ..., Yn be a random sample from a Beta(1,$\theta$) population.  Derive the MLE for $\theta$.

Getting started, I set up the likelihood function as:

$$
L(\theta) = \frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-Y_i)^{\theta-1}
$$

This simplifies to:

$$
L(\theta) = \theta(1-Y_i)^{n(\theta-1)}
$$

Taking the log:

$$
l(L) = log(\theta) + n(\theta-1)log(1-Y_i)
$$

Take the derivative:

$$
\frac{dl}{d\theta} = \frac{1}{\theta}+nlog(1-Y_i)
$$

Solve for $\theta$:

$$
\theta = \frac{-1}{nlog(1-Y_i)}
$$

But this can't be right as I've not dealt with the summation of $Y_i$.  In most examples I've seen, this goes away as a result of the summation being divided by n,b ut in this case I can't find where I've gone wrong.

I appreciate any tips.

Comment: You can't write $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-Y_i)^{\theta-1}=(1-Y_i)^{n(\theta-1)}$, different $i$ indicates different values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your likelihood fucntion is wrong, for your Beta distrbution, the $pdf$ is

$$f(y)=\frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)}(1-y)^{\theta-1}$$
The likelihood function will be

$L(\theta)=\frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)}(1-y_1)^{\theta-1}\frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)}(1-y_2)^{\theta-1}...\frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)}(1-y_n)^{\theta-1}\\= (\frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)})^n\left [ \prod_{i=1}^n(1-y_i)\right]^{\theta-1}$

Now take the log

$l(\theta)=nlog(\frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)})+(\theta-1)\sum_{i=1}^nlog(1-y_i)$

I will not go ahead from here.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I corrected an error in my original post, but I don't think it affects your response.  I see the position of the exponent is together, and you have no theta to start - don't the Gamma functions simplify to theta?

Comment: "Together" should be "different" on that last comment.

Comment: Ah-ha!  I also pulled the Gamma functions out without bringing along the exponent n.

Comment: Is there any needed to keep the Gamma functions in this form?  This reduces to theta, no?  And then theta^n once pulled outside the product.

Comment: Not need, since $ \frac{\Gamma(1+\theta)}{\Gamma(\theta)}=\frac{\theta !}{(\theta-1)!}=\theta$